# Gradient transparency turns to grey

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, gradient

I have a problem with gradient in Illustrator
from black 100% to black 0% transparency, the transition between them appears grey

[image: https://i.imgur.com/GHnzRBR.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the underlying color a spot color?

In general, it's merely a drawing issue in Illustrator previewing color builds in CMYK mode, most commonly with spot color usage. Illustrator can't effectively produce a preview for a blend from CMYK to spot.

The *easiest* solution is to use a black to blue gradient, not black to transparent.

If this isn't feasible, and that blue is *not* a spot color, then set the gradient object blend mode to `Multiply`. If that blue *is* a spot color, set the gradient object to `Overprint` the blue.

Comment: thank you very much, i totally forgot about the blending mode, the blue background was also a radial gradient